# Testing if beamer body is empty

Tags: beamer, conditionals, body

I would like to test the frame body, if it is empty:

1. add some words;
2. discard this frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\what{}{}{}{} ?
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First frame}
Something here....
\end{frame}


%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second frame}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third frame}
%%Some comments
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

By Some code pre-defined, i want the second/third frame work like this

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second frame}
(Hey, you forgot something!)
\end{frame}

---

and i find some clues:

\preto\frame{\ifelsethen{}{}{\add-some-tex}}

\pretocmd{\what-commands}{beamer@checknoslide}{}{}{}

\ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else ... \fi

and i think the key change perhaps is:

texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty  ->

```
\long\def\beamer@doseveralframes#1{%
  \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty\else%
    % Again stuff
    \expandafter \gdef\csname beamer@again@\beamer@againname\endcsname{{#1}}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
  \loop%
  \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
  \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{}%
  \def\beamer@doifinframe{\begin{beamer@frameslide}%
    #1%
  \end{beamer@frameslide}}%
```

anyone can step further ?

the 'empty/blank'  perhaps contain "linebreaks"