# Auto detect blank page and add something

Tags: beamer, patching, frame

i have a beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\what{}{}{}{} ?
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{First}

Something.
}


\frame{\frametitle{Second}

}


\frame{\frametitle{Third}

%%Some comments

}
\end{document}
```

i want the second and third auto add "This is a empty frame" in the frame and still keep the frametitle .

How ?

Comment: Is this different from your previous question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600304/testing-if-beamer-body-is-empty

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes, i forgot it. :-(, but no one answered

Comment: and i find some clues:  
  \preto\frame{\ifelsethen{}{}{\add-some-tex}}, 
   \pretocmd{\what-commands}{beamer@checknoslide}{}{}{}, anyone can step further ?

Comment: and this : \ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else%
 \ifdefempty{\subsecname}{\relax}{%
  ~--~\insertsubsectionhead%
 }%
\fi  change this "\ifx\insertsubsection\empty"?

Comment: @ZenoShuai: This will be closed as a duplicate. Please edit your previous question and update the body of it with the information you found.

Comment: @Peter Can u close the previous one , pls ?

Comment: @ZenoShuai: This duplicate question is now closed. But, please do update the older question with the info you mentioned here in the comments.